# XUnit Test a Service that is an internal sealed class with protected override async Task methods

Tags: xunit

```
// I can reach the TestVisibility in my xUnit, but not the NameOfMethod.
// This IS NOT ACUTAL CODE.  Sorry, I can't use actual code, so I'm trying to make this as basic as // it can be

//SERVICE
[assembly: InternalVisibleTo(name of unit test)]
namespace whatevername.service
{
   internal sealed class service
   {
      public service(){}
   }

   protected override async Task NameofMethod(){}
   public void TestVisibility(){}
}


//XUNIT TEST
using whatevername.service // references are included besides this 

namespace whatevername.service.test
{
   public class NameOfTest
   {

      [Fact]
      public asyn Task NameofMethodTest()
      {
         // arrange
            Service service = new Service();
         // act
            await service.NameofMethod(); //  NameofMethod is not reachable.
            service.TestVisibility();  // IS reachable. 
         // assert
      }
}
```

I just need to know how to be able to test that protected method inside of the internal sealed class.
When I type service.  the public method shows up, but not the protected.

If I make it public it is visible, but I don't want to do that for testing.
There must be a proper way of setting up XUNIT, I stress XUNIT because that is what we use, so there are no other options here because I don't control that in this environment, to do this.

Do I setup a subclass in the unit test that somehow references this?

I've searched the site for solutions, but I couldn't find one that went this deep that deals with internal sealed classes with protected methods.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with xUnit, just C#. There are a couple of options:

1. Make the method `protected internal`. Disadvantage: This does open up the method to other classes within the same assembly.
2. Make the method `private protected`, unseal the class, and create a derived class in your test. Disadvantage: the class is no longer sealed.
3. Rethink your API. Unit tests should test observable behavior. A unit test shouldn't even know that method *exists*, much less call it. The fact that the unit test cannot do what it needs to do indicates a design issue in the system under test; perhaps you need a strategy pattern or some similar refactoring.